# Is there a justification for the Bernoulli deviance in the R stats package?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, bernoulli-distribution, deviance

Using the standard `glm(...)` function in R for Bernoulli regression, it appears that the residual deviance has the same value as the binomial deviance where each observation is calculated with $n_i=1$ [1]. Is there a reason for this formula?
Should it improve any properties? For example, the actual Bernoulli deviance should not be used as a goodness-of-fit measure in logistic regression [2]. However, I cannot see how this would address the problem.

Thanks a lot!

[1] Unfortunately, I could not open the source code for `.Call(C_binomial_dev_resids, y, mu, wt)` used in the `binomial()` function, but found this question ([understanding deviance residual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304268/understanding-how-r-calculates-deviance-residuals)) where a formula is presented for the package *binomTools*. The result of the deviance did also coincide with the tests I did on `glm(...)` for Bernoulli regression.
[2] Dunn, P.K., Smyth, G.K. (2018). Chapter 9: Models for Proportions: Binomial GLMs. In: Generalized Linear Models With Examples in R. [Link to relevant Section 9.10](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4419-0118-7_9#Sec10)

Comment: Yes, the residual deviance has the same value as the binomial deviance where each observation is calculated with n=1. That is the definition of the residual deviance for Bernoulli regression! What else did you expect it to be? The residual deviance for Bernoulli regression is derived in the same way as for any generalized linear model. The reasoning and derivations are given in many references including the Dunn & Smyth (2018) textbook that you cite.